# Adding Bing search result to contacts?

Tags: contacts, bing

I was wondering if there was a direct way to add info on a business from a Bing search to a new contact (or even an existing one) in your address book. There are some businesses that I may contact regularly, like my pharmacy, car dealership, or local pizza place. Currently in order to get them into my contacts, I have to copy the info in manually, one by one. I can add a place as a favorite on the map (star it) but this doesn't put it in my contacts, which I would prefer. Can this be done? Or am I already doing all I can for now?

Comment: As your contacts can be synchronized you would more likely want to look for a solution on your computer because I doubt if you could find this on your phone.

Comment: @TomWijsman Well, I often use Local Scout or Bing Search on my phone to find local businesses and other info like phone numbers and hours, so a solution on my phone would be most convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not integrated, I use the app Add To Contacts. If I search with Bing, it will capture all the information and swipe over to "apps" and you can tap to automatically add.

Answer (score 3):

On the phone, there are 2 ways that you can do it.

When looking at the Bing Local results (for piza, let's say).

1. Click on the result you want. Then click the star with the plus sign in the toolbar. This will add a favorite.
2. If you want it in your contacts, touch the number to dial. Promptly hang up. Go to your call history. Touch the pizza joint you called. It should be listed by name.  when the contact card opens, click the save icon.

Comment: I use the second method. Unfortunately it doesn't pick up other meta data though, like website and address. I was hoping there could be a way that picks that up automatically too. Thanks though.